# FAILED CONFIGURATION: @BeforeMethod setUp java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/google/common/base/Function

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, testng

Newly setup the eclipse and and TestNG. I have downloaded the Jar file zip from selenium website but on execution of example FAILED CONFIGURATION: @BeforeMethod setUp java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: is coming

```
  import org.testng.annotations.AfterMethod;
  import org.testng.annotations.Test;
  import org.testng.annotations.BeforeMethod;
  import org.testng.Assert;
  import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;
  import org.openqa.selenium.*;
  import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver;

 public class Login {
 private WebDriver driver;
 private String baseUrl;
 private boolean acceptNextAlert = true;
 private StringBuffer verificationErrors = new StringBuffer();

 @BeforeMethod 
 public void setUp() throws Exception {
 driver = new FirefoxDriver();
 baseUrl = "http://tssgmsw006:8080";
 driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(30, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
 }

 @Test
 public void testLogin() throws Exception {
 driver.get(baseUrl + "/GSSR/views/supplierSelectionAction.action");
 driver.findElement(By.linkText("Advanced")).click();
 driver.findElement(By.linkText("Basic")).click();
 }

  @AfterMethod public void tearDown() throws Exception {
  driver.quit();
  String verificationErrorString = verificationErrors.toString();
  if (!"".equals(verificationErrorString)) {
  Assert.fail(verificationErrorString);
    }
   }
  }
```

Output:-

```
   FAILED CONFIGURATION: @BeforeMethod setUp java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/google/common/base/Function
```

Comment: Are you using Maven?What artifacts or which JARs you have on the classpath?

Comment: I'm downloaded the selenium-2.37.0 from selenium website and add in libraries ...

Answer (score 0):

Add all the jar files present in the srcs folder of this zip file to the build path in eclipse.

`http://selenium.googlecode.com/files/selenium-java-2.37.0.zip`

Comment: @user2991271 please mark this answer as accepted if it fixed your issue by clicking the ✔ next to it.

Comment: Go to "Selenium Client & WebDriver Language Bindings" section in this link
http://www.seleniumhq.org/download/
and download java bindings. There you will find the required jars.

Answer (score 0):

I too faced the same issue. But If you add all JAR files including bin folder this error can get resolve.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).